# Find between now and later time lowest value

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a rails conditional statement that states, among other conditions:

```
where(['[...],hour_id >= ? AND hour_id <= ?', [...] session[:hour], @end_period)
```

the hours are indexed via their 24-hour clock number.

This condition is incomplete as the need is to extract the record which is true for the **lowest** valid hour of that span.  i.e. we are at hour 13 and we have objects at hours 17, 18 and 19. At present it can extract any of 17, 18 and 19; this needs to be restricted to '17'.

Answer (score 0):

Order the items by the hour and pick the first:

```
where(:hour_id => (session[:hour]..@end_period)).order(:hour_id).first
```

Btw you can use this range syntax to query for a value that should between to other values.

Comment: This helped... me clarify the problem.  Unfortunately the where condition needs to call all, as the condition has to be met in the entire range.  The resulting array is being cherry picked by the application and is showing one of the three values.  Thus the underlying mechanics are running properly but the view is plopping out data that surprises a bit.  I guess they could be re-ordered before presentation... and a shortcut is to ignore it as the start of the range is a working parameter.